# VB script to list folders and contents

Tags: vbscript

I would like to write a VB script that will:

List all folders named "abc", and also there contents, in share drive \share1

Currently these folders named "abc" are located all over the place in \share1, but they all have the same name.

The issue I have is that some of these paths are long paths, hence getting this working through PowerShell has been very difficult, as it keeps hitting the 260 limit.

Comment: 260 chars is a Windows limit. What makes you think that VBScript would do better than PowerShell?

Comment: Fair enough, what would you suggest as a work around?

Comment: vbscript is not vb.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prefixing a path with `\\?\` allows paths up to 32,000 odd characters. This allows apps to opt in to very long file names as they crash most programs. Now it depends on how you access the file functions if the component will allow you. CMD does support this.

so a command line

```
for /f %A in ('dir c:\windows\abc /s /b /ad') do dir "\\?\%A"
```

`\\?\` works with unc paths too.

```
for /f %A in ('dir \\?\c:\windows\abc /s /b /ad') do dir "%A"
```

Comment: Nice one. I found an MSDN article about this as well. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think that RoboCopy (the Windows utility) is your best bet. This can handle long path names, and it can actually be used to just list files, rather than copy them, by using the 
`/L option` (: List only - don’t copy, timestamp or delete any files.)

http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html provides a good summary of all the options.

You can also download a GUI for it which might make it a bit easier to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to shorten the path via [`subst`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491006.aspx):

```
subst X: C:\very\...\long\...\path
```